# Can I manually resolve dependency conflicts (SolverProblemError) in poetry?

Tags: python, dependencies, python-poetry

I decided to use `poetry`, and everything was going well, adding the dependencies of my existing project modules as they were required.
When I tried to add the googlesearch-python package I got this SolverProblemError:

> ```
> (.env) C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Documents\Master_s_thesis\Code\Mastersthesis>poetry add googlesearch-python
> Using version ^2020.0.2 for googlesearch-python
>
> Updating dependencies
> Resolving dependencies...
>
>   SolverProblemError
>
>   Because googlesearch-python (2020.0.2) depends on beautifulsoup4 (4.9.1) which depends on soupsieve (<2.0), googlesearch-python (2020.0.2) requires soupsieve (<2.0).
>   And because googlesearch-python (2020.0.2) depends on soupsieve (2.0.1), googlesearch-python is forbidden.
>   So, because no versions of googlesearch-python match >2020.0.2,<2021.0.0
>    and mastersthesis depends on googlesearch-python (^2020.0.2), version solving failed.
>
>   at ~\.poetry\lib\poetry\puzzle\solver.py:241 in _solve
>       237│             packages = result.packages
>       238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
>       239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
>       240│         except SolveFailure as e:
>     → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
>       242│
>       243│         results = dict(
>       244│             depth_first_search(
>       245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes
> ```

After some tweaking, not exactly sure what I did tbh, I can run the dependent files normally, inside or outside my .env venv. But I still can't add googlesearch-python. I have added other packages after this with no problem.

I tried editing the project.toml file directly, bringing beautifulsoup4 to ^4.9.1 down from ^4.9.3, but it didn't have any effect.